# Boost tcp stream with filtering input stream causes hang

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, stream, boost-asio

Consider the following:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, message& p)
{
    typedef boost::archive::binary_iarchive in;  
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream fis;
    fis.push(is, 0);
    in stream(fis);
    stream >> p;

    return is;
}
```

where `message& p`is a serializable structure, and `std::istream& is` is a tcp stream.

The server waits for the client to send data inside the `in stream(fis);` constructor, and it continues when data has been received. The `stream` object serializes the data from the tcp stream to the `message` object.

Now, when actually filtering the received data by adding the following:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, message& p)
{
    typedef boost::archive::binary_iarchive in;  
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream fis;
    fis.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor(), 0);
    fis.push(is, 0);
    in stream(fis);
    stream >> p;

    return is;
}
```

it *should* read the data from the tcp stream, decompress it and serialize it to the `message` object. But instead, it hangs on `in stream(fis);` and returns after the data has been sent 10-20 times or the client disconnects.

I've already tried to set zlib decompressor's internal buffer to both 0 and 1, where 0 fails an assert and 1 somehow works only once(throws on second iteration). I've also set `filtering_istream` buffers to 0, so that shouldn't cause the hang. I also noticed, that if the `std::istream& is` is a file stream, it works correctly.

So why does the function hang on the `in stream(fis);` when using tcp stream? Does it have something to do with the zlib's way it handles the buffer, or is it something `filtering_istream` specific? I'd also like to hear some workaround to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You already answered question by yourself ;)

> I also noticed, that if the std::istream& is is a file stream, it works correctly.

`filtering_istream` is polling until it get EOF, so because TCP stream ends only on client disconnect - it does not end stream reading. On `ifstream` it simple get his EOF and ends processing.

Comment: The filtering istream works when the zlib_decompressor isn't added, so I guess it doesn't depend on the EOF flag

Comment: @weggo so maybe exactly `zlib_decompressor` is part who waiting EOF ? **gzip** works exactly like that in both file and pipe modes.

Comment: Hmm.. That probably is the reason then

Comment: @weggo you must split tcp stream somehow; some indicator which means compressed stream end. For example, compressed data length before stream. But, you will need to stop `zlib_decompressor` by count of bytes processed. Dont have experience with boost iostreams but seems this can be done with `io::read`